# Отображение vk mini app на ios устройствах

Tags: html, css, reactjs, vk-mini-apps

Разрабатываю vk mini app на reactjs. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: на андроид и декстопе все отображается корректно, но потом запустил на iphone SE 2020 и увидел, что у IOS статус бар наезжает на body. Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
.main-page-container {
  padding-top: 55px;
}
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  .main-page-container {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
.fixed-header {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  .fixed-header {
    padding: 30px 15px 5px;
  }
}
```

Далее открыл на Iphone 13 pro и увидел, что там другая высота статус бара и приложение отображается некорректно.

Может кто подсказать, как можно решить данную проблему?

Библиотеку vkui не использую, делаю только на своих компонентах.